# If-Else in T-SQL where clause

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Just wondering what's the best way to do a conditional WHERE clause in a T-sql sproc? I don't want to use dynamic sql - I'd rather use a paramaterised sproc.

My params can't be NULL, but they can be an empty string. If they are an empty string, I'd like to 'skip' that part of the where clause.

Without the if/else it looks like this;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyProc]
(
    @Criteria1 nvarchar(50),
    @Criteria2 nvarchar(50),
    @Criteria3 nvarchar(50)
)
AS
SELECT top 250 * FROM [MyTable]
where
Col1 LIKE '%' + @Criteria1 + '%' and
Col2 LIKE '%' + @Criteria2 + '%' and
Col3 LIKE '%' + @Criteria3 + '%'
```

For performance reasons, I'd like to skip the LIKE search for a particular criteria if that criteria is '' (empty string).

thanks

Comment: Be sure to understand that `Col_n LIKE '%' + @Criteria1 + '%'` performs an indexed-scan at best, and a table-scan at worst, due to the leading wildcard in the **like pattern**. If your data-table is of any size, you will want to rethink this design sooner rather then later.

Comment: Thank you Pieter. I'm going to drop the leading %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT top 250 * FROM [MyTable]
where
(@Criteria1 = '' or Col1 LIKE '%' + @Criteria1 + '%') and
(@Criteria2 = '' or Col2 LIKE '%' + @Criteria2 + '%') and
(@Criteria3 = '' or Col3 LIKE '%' + @Criteria3 + '%')
```

Here's some test code

```
create table MyTable
(
    id int identity,
    col1 nvarchar(50),
    col2 nvarchar(50),
    col3 nvarchar(50)
)
go

insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values( '', '', '');
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values( '', '', 'a');
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values( '', 'a', 'b');
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values( 'a', 'b', 'c');
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values( 'b', 'c', '');
insert into MyTable(col1, col2, col3) values( 'c', '', '');

-- select * from MyTable; 
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [MyProc]
(
    @Criteria1 nvarchar(50),
    @Criteria2 nvarchar(50),
    @Criteria3 nvarchar(50)
)
AS
    select  *
    from    MyTable
    where
    (@Criteria1 = '' or Col1 LIKE '%' + @Criteria1 + '%') and
    (@Criteria2 = '' or Col2 LIKE '%' + @Criteria2 + '%') and
    (@Criteria3 = '' or Col3 LIKE '%' + @Criteria3 + '%') 
go

exec MyProc '', '', '';
exec MyProc 'a', '', '';
exec MyProc '', 'a', '';
exec MyProc '', '', 'a';
```

Comment: You're right. But it's not just the AND/OR, it's also the '=' instead of '!='.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` to check for empty string.

```
SELECT top 250 * FROM [MyTable]
where
(@Criteria1 = '' or Col1 LIKE '%' + @Criteria1 + '%') and
(@Criteria2 = '' or Col2 LIKE '%' + @Criteria2 + '%') and
(@Criteria3 = '' or Col3 LIKE '%' + @Criteria3 + '%')
```

For each condition if `@Criteria1 = ''` the OR condition will short-circuit and the second part of the criteria (with LIKE) will not be evaluated.